# How to decrease padding in NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-number-picker

How to decrease padding in NumberPicker

[image]

I want something like it:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change vertical spacing in Android NumberPicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056744/how-to-change-vertical-spacing-in-android-numberpicker)

Comment: i need number picker not data\time picker

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's surprisingly easy to archive:

[image]
(`scaleX` and `scaleY` equals 2.5)

[image]
(without `scaleX` and `scaleY`)

```
    String[] values = {"Public", "Shared", "Private",....};

    NumberPicker np=
            (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    np.setMaxValue(values.length-1);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

And simply set small **`layout_height`** and **`scaleX`**, **`scaleX`**:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:scaleX="2.5"
    android:scaleY="2.5"/>
```

I do agree, that standard `NumberPicker` is hardly customizable, though.

I hope, it helps

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, number picker is not style-able.

I advise on using a library such as the [one by SimonTV](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a bit late but you can set the explicit height on the `NumberPicker` it then follows the given height and adjusts the space between the items.

Comment: `android:layout_height="120dp"` makes it beautiful for me

Answer (score 1):

As Grebulon pointed its very simple to customize the picker if you are using the libray by [image: simon TV] .

These are the code and the results-

```
<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:internalMaxHeight="100dp"
        app:selectionDividersDistance="30dp"/>
```

I was forked it once to increase the number of selector wheels.
Here is the output of above code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to decrease the height of the NumberPicker that will result in decrease of internal spacing between the numbers as well, in my case I have set it to 120dp and that just does the job

```
android:layout_height="120dp"
```

Here is the complete code for my NumberPicker

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/myNumberPicker" />
```

For styling I have used the following theme in my style file

```
<!-- Custom style for Number Picker -->
<style name="myNumberPicker" parent="Theme.MyApplication">
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorBlue</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semi_bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize your `NumberPicker` Theme like below:

```
    <style name="Widget.Holo.NumberPicker" parent="Widget.NumberPicker">
  <!-- Customize your theme here -->
  <item name="android:selectionDivider">@android:drawable/numberpicker_selection_divider</item>
  <item name="android:selectionDividerHeight">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:selectionDividersDistance">25dp</item>
  <item name="android:internalMinWidth">50dp</item>
  <item name="android:internalMaxHeight">100dp</item>

</style>
```

Hope it's help your.

Comment: I can't set any item. It says that it is forbidden.